# Why do I get a whisper like sound when I play my violin?

Tags: violin

I am new to the violin, and am teaching myself. When I play the violin with the bow, a weird whisper like sound comes out, rather than a clean sound that most violin players achieve. Why is it that I get this whisper like sound?

Comment: You might need to rosin your bow more.

Comment: I'll look into that.

Comment: Also, it will take you a while to perfect 'bow control', lack of which could be a contributing factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out why the whispery like sound came with the help of @Jomiddnz! The reason was because of my rosining! I hadn't applied enough rosin on my bow. Just apply more rosin, and there you go!